# Count occurences of values in table, when I treat one value as occurence of all other values

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table with one column (just to simplify the problem) with values 0-23 or *.
I want to count occurrences of each value 0-23, but treat * as occurrence of all other values
for example:

```
column_name
-------------
3
4
5
6
7
*
4
4
3
*
```

I want to get something like that:

```
column_name | count
--------------------
1           | 2
2           | 2
3           | 4
4           | 5
5           | 3
6           | 3
7           | 3
.....
```

I tried experimenting with different count and "group by" methods, but always getting very strange results. Basically the main problem here is to how count rows when I need to have one value in all other groups.

Comment: Do you have multiple * and if so, do you count per *?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple * and each one counts as one occurrence of all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use analytic function that counts values where * is replaced by actual value between 0 and 23:

```sql
SELECT      DISTINCT n.RN "COL_1", Count(REPLACE(t.COL_1, '*', n.RN)) OVER(Partition By n.RN) "CNT"
FROM        tbl t
INNER JOIN  ( Select To_Char(LEVEL - 1) "RN" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <=24  ) n ON(n.RN = REPLACE(t.COL_1, '*', n.RN))
WHERE       n.RN IN(SELECT COL_1 FROM tbl)
ORDER BY    To_Number(n.RN)
```

which with your sample data:

```sql
WITH
  tbl (COL_1) AS
    (
      Select '3' From Dual Union  All
      Select '4' From Dual Union  All
      Select '5' From Dual Union  All
      Select '6' From Dual Union  All
      Select '7' From Dual Union  All
      Select '*' From Dual Union  All
      Select '4' From Dual Union  All
      Select '4' From Dual Union  All
      Select '3' From Dual Union  All
      Select '*' From Dual Union  All
      Select '3' From Dual 
    )
```

... results as:

```sql
COL_1                                           CNT
---------------------------------------- ----------
3                                                 5 
4                                                 5 
5                                                 3 
6                                                 3 
7                                                 3
```

... and if you exclude the Where clause you will get all the rows (0 - 23) with number of occurances counted by REPLACE of * with any of the numbers

```sql
COL_1                                           CNT
---------------------------------------- ----------
0                                                 2 
1                                                 2 
2                                                 2 
3                                                 5 
4                                                 5 
5                                                 3 
6                                                 3 
7                                                 3 
8                                                 2 
9                                                 2 
10                                                2 
11                                                2 
12                                                2 
13                                                2 
14                                                2 
15                                                2 
16                                                2 
17                                                2 
18                                                2 
19                                                2 
20                                                2 
21                                                2 
22                                                2 
23                                                2
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! Lightweight, clean and easily scalable to my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using successive `WITH`'s :

First one to calculate number of occurrence of *.

And the second is to calculate number of occurrence of each number.

```
with cte as (
  select count(1) as c
  from mytable
  where column_name = '*'
),
cte2 as (
  select column_name, count(1) as c
  from mytable, cte
  group by column_name
)
select column_name, cte.c + cte2.c
from cte2, cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with nested statements too,

```
SELECT ID,(count_ + (
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM sql_test_a
    WHERE ID = '*')) as count_ 
FROM (
   SELECT ID,COUNT(ID) as count_ 
   FROM sql_test_a WHERE ID != '*' GROUP BY ID);
```